Conjecture: There is no pair of integer rectangles for which the first has twice the second's perimeter and the second has twice the first's area
The book Mathematics for Human Flourishing by Francis Su contains several challenges. One among them is:

Problem: Find a pair of rectangles for which the first has twice the perimeter of the second and the second has twice the area of the first.

Getting a general solution parameterized for real numbers was the easy part, but to add challenge I tried to find an integer solution. When I could not find one, I challenged myself to prove that there are no integer solutions. What follows is my proof attempt. I have no idea if it's leading in the right direction or not, and I have little/no experience with diophantine equations. Brute force computation (if I coded it correctly) shows no solutions exist at least until very large numbers.
Conjecture: There are no entirely-integer solutions to the problem stated above.
Proof sketch: We'll use x and y to denote the lengths of the first rectangle and X and Y to denote those for the second rectangle. Let P and A denote the perimeter and area of the second rectangle. We can model the problem with the equations:
$XY = A = 2xy$
$2(X+Y) = P = x + y$
Rearranging as a quadratic and solving the two simultaneous sets of equations gives (this part I do not need evaluated).
$x,y = \frac{P\pm\sqrt{P^2-2A}}{2}$
$X,Y = \frac{\frac{P}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{P^2}{4}- 4A}}{2}$
So we can only have a rational solution if both discriminants $P^2-2A$ and $\frac{P^2}{4}- 4A$ are perfect squares. Thus we have for some integers $k$ and $m$,
$P^2 - 2A = k^2$ (Eqn. 1)
$\frac{P^2}{4}- 4A = m^2$
Multiplying both sides of the second equation by 4, we can derive:
${P^2}- 16A = 4m^2$ (Eqn. 2)
Eliminating variables $A$ and $P$ Equations 1 and 2 gives the following:
$7P^2 = 4(2k^2 - m^2)$ (Eqn. 3)
$14A = k^2 - 4m^2$ (Eqn. 4)
From here on I have been stuck. I want to show that this system of equations has no integer solutions. I have tried deriving a contradiction using the 2-adic or 7-adic valuations. I have also tried re-parameterizing the problem by letting $c = P$ and $b = \sqrt{2A}$, so that I could try to find solutions in terms of Pythagorean triples, but that did not lead me to a solution either, plus that method requires that $A$ is a perfect square, which is not necessarily true.

What can I try next?

